# Put computer to sleep, left it for 2+ hours, came back and it shutdown and won't turn on

Tags: hardware-failure, troubleshooting, power

I built my computer maybe 5 months ago, and it has been running fine up until a couple of weeks ago when I had it in suspend, and then it decided to shutdown and wouldn't turn back on. So I tried resetting the mobo (is that correct?) with the little 3 pin arrangement on the board. I then tried booting up again and got nothing, so I left it plugged in overnight, and when I woke up in the morning it was on and so was my monitor (Nobody touched it.).

Weird, I thought. I just hope it doesn't happen again.

And it did. Same problem. The light for the Ethernet port will blink, and the LED on my GPU will turn on, but no fans spin and I get no image on the monitor.

Specs:

- mobo: ASRock H97M Pro4
- RAM: G.SKILL Ripjaws 8GB
- CPU: Intel Core i5 4440
- PSU: Corsair CX500M
- GPU: ASUD GTX 660
- two HDDs

Comment: When I have a problem that seems like it might be a system going to sleep and not coming back, I generally turn the display, HD, and computer sleep timers off to see if that's a factor.

Comment: I had read about that and I'll look into it. But I still can't get the computer to turn on. Any advice with that?

Comment: Does the power supply have a fan that's not spinning when you try to turn it on?

Comment: No fans are turning on when the power button is pressed on my case.

Comment: Ok, based on the GPU powering on but not the power supply fan it's kind of ambiguous whether the power supply is actually on or not.  You haven't ruled anything out. This is the stage where I usually try to add components one by one to see if something specific is making the power supply (or motherboard power logic) refuse to start.

Comment: Ah okay I'll try this tomorrow. Not enough time tonight.

Comment: pull the power cord and do a hard reset by holding the power button in for 15 seconds, connect the power cord and attempt power up, see if anything changes,